# wrap pagination in class

Tags: channel, pagination, parse

I have a basic channel and I want the pagination to be at the top.

I have got a pagination limit of 20 and output it like this

{if '{count}'=='20' OR '{absolute_count}'=='{total_results}'}
  {paginate} {pagination_links}{/paginate}
 {/if}

This is fine but the pagination appears **after** the div. I really need it inside to control my responsive layout. Can this be achieved by adding a class to the pagination tag or some other way. It must be parsed last I guess which is causing the issue.

**FIXED - add the class inside the {paginate} tag I thought this would wrap around EVERY link but it just adds a wrapper**

```
{if '{count}'=='20' OR '{absolute_count}'=='{total_results}'}
  {paginate} <div class="large-24 columns"> {pagination_links}</div>{/paginate}</div>
 {/if}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use quotation marks for this conditionals. `{if count == '20' OR absolute_count == total_results}` should be fine.

Comment: Please, answer your own question and mark it as right.

Answer (score 2):

The position of pagination is defined by the [parameter paginate](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html#paginate):

- if it is set as `top`, the pagination code will be removed before parsing and added back at the top of the parsing results;
- if it's set as `bottom`, the pagination code will be added to the bottom of the results;
- set it as `both`and it will be... Well, I got the idea;
- `hidden` doesn't show the pagination;
- if you want to choose where to show the pagination code, set the parameter as `inline`.

The `inline` is available since [version 2.6](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-6-0), but a lot of people doesn't know about it yet. Even I never used it.

Comment: Good answer! I've never heard of the `inline` value until now.

Answer (score 0):

If memory servers me correctly the EE pagination positioning is quite restrictive and thickle.

I believe i got round this in the past by letting EE render the pagination as it wants and then using jQuery to get the contents of the pagination DIV and insert it into the actual div i wanted it to appear in.

So after the page/pagination is loaded. Run a function a bit like this....

```
function movePagination() {
    $originalPagination = $("#originalPaginationContainingDiv").html();
    $("#destinationDivForPagination").html($originalPagination);
}
```

Note: I have not tested this.

Comment: this wasn't it but it led me to the workaround